# SIGSEGV error when using shared memory in C++

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, shared-memory

I'm doing a very simple IPC between two applications on a raspberry pi in Linux, where one applications sends and the other one receives

During an overnight run, the process crashed with a `SIGSEGV` error.

It crashed on `strcpy(str, in_string);` in the sending application

What would cause this type of crash?

The strings Im writing into memory are all the same size, and Im assuming its always writing to the same memory location, but I know linux uses virtual memory, so the physical address may be shifting.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream> 
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/shm.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

class LocalSocket {
public:

    LocalSocket() 
    {         // ftok to generate unique key 
        key_t key = ftok("shmfile", 65); 

        // shmget returns an identifier in shmid 
        shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0666 | IPC_CREAT); 

        // shmat to attach to shared memory 
        str = (char*) shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0); 
    }

    ~LocalSocket()
    {   
        //detach from shared memory  
        shmdt(str); 

        // destroy the shared memory 
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL); 
    }

    int shmid;
    char *str;   

    bool Send(char* in_string)
    {
        strcpy(str, in_string);

        printf("Data written in memory: %s\n", str); 


        return true;
    }

    bool Receive(char* out_string)
    {   
        printf("Data read from memory: %s\n", str); 

        strcpy(out_string, str);

        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you ensure that `Receive()` runs after `Send()` has finished?

Comment: The size of the shared memory is specified in `shmget()`.

Comment: I don't, does it require a a mutex? Whats the best way for one application to signal another? SIGUSR?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you might try to read before anything has been written.

Comment: The lack of any cross-process mutexes means that if "send" is called at the same time as "receive" between both processes there would be overlapping strcpy operations occurring on that buffer.

Comment: But the most obvious reason for a crash is because your code isn't checking for nullptr on the return from shmat.  Ditto for checking the return value from the other apis include shmget.

Comment: is there a way to do an atomic operation using shared memory? For instance, 1 byte in shared memory that would indicate whether its ready to read from or write to? I tried using SIGUSR but it causes exceptions in debugger.

Comment: I moved shmget and shmat out of the Send and Receive functions, so they only get called once

Comment: You can create cross-process mutex with a semaphore (semop, semget, etc...).  I suspect there are modern equivalents with better APIs these days.

Comment: My money is on breaking the rule of 0/3/5